# US Citizen Overstayed German Tourist Visa while applying for Family Reunification Visa

Tags: usa, visa, germany, us-citizens, family

My husband and I are both American citizens and moved to Germany approximately 5 months ago. I have a work visa from my job, but my husband does not (he's received a work-study offer, pending his family re-unification visa, however). My company set us up with a relocation specialist to advise and assist us with the visa process.

Honestly, its been a complete disaster working with them. They have given us terrible at worst and incomplete at best advice. When we first arrived, I was concerned about the type of visa my husband was on. The company told me several times that he's on the same visa terms as me, and not to worry about it. I pressed for more information, but they shut me down.

Now my case has been reviewed by another agent at the company. He informed me that my husband has been on a tourist visa this whole time, that he has overstayed his visa by two months, and that they have reported him to the authorities for overstaying his visa.

I am completely blindsided by this. I have reached out to an insurance agent recommended by a friend to get legal insurance. I am also asking around if anyone knows an immigration lawyer. But besides this, I'm at a complete loss as to what to do.

My husband can go home and wait for the family re-unification visa - thats never been a problem. Should he leave now? Is it too late? Should I tell my company what's happened?

Comment: Go to the immigration office togeather with your husband. Ask if his dependency residence permit was applied for togeather with yours. If yes, his stay is legal until a final decision has been made. If not apply for it. Inform them, when they ask (and they will) who in your firm was responsible for your (and your husband's) application.

Comment: If your company hired a 3rd party to deal with your application, then yes you should inform them of the situation.

Comment: Do not directly go to the immigration office like Mark Johnson suggested. Rather, find a lawyer in Germany who is specialised in immigration law and consult him before going there.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.